# OpenLayers 4 cant´t reproject json file

Tags: openlayers

Hi I load a set of Json points from my server, the points
are stored in EPSG 32720, which is UTM 20S, and also for testing the same points
are stored in EPSG 4326 coordinates.

Using Open Layers 3.8.2, i load the two files and can see how the points of 
EPSG 32720 are reprojected and perfect match drawing one circle inside the EPSG 4326 points.

But when use Open layers 4 the reprojection fail, 
the point are displayed in another country.
the documentation is little different.
(i only can write 2 links)

The problem is that i try 4 options:

```
    proj4.defs("EPSG:32720","+proj=utm +zone=20 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs");     
var sourceProj = ol.proj.get('EPSG:32720');

1) var UTMFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON({defaultDataProjection: sourceProj});
2) var UTMFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON({defaultDataProjection: 'EPSG:32720'});

3)var UTMFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON({featureProjection: 'EPSG:32720'});
4)var UTMFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON({defaultDataProjection:'EPSG:32720', featureProjection: 'EPSG:32720'});

 var vectorLayer32720 = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({            
            url: '/static/centroids32720.geojson',            
            format: UTMFormat
        }),
    style: stylePointsBlue    
   });
```

Only the 1 and 2 work with OL 3.8.2,
 but can figure what is wrong?
 I make two plunker samples one with 3.8.2 and the other with version 4.

Version 3.8.2
https://plnkr.co/edit/RNE48KkEKqiAnAd0Ssu2?p=preview

Version 4
 https://plnkr.co/edit/DvwImnvi8looJRZYOjB6?p=preview

Someone can tell me what is wrong.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your GeoJSON contains the deprecated `crs` element, which is respected by OpenLayers 4.x. But your proj4 definition uses a different code. To fix your example for OpenLayers 4.x, define an alias for the data projection like this:

```
proj4.defs('urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::32720', proj4.defs('EPSG:32720');
```

For the vector source that reads the EPSG:32720 GeoJSON, just use

```
format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
```

without any constructor options.

Note: According to the ISO standard, GeoJSON should always be in geographic coordinates (EPSG:4326).

Answer (score 0):

Great thanks for your answer.

With you solution work good, also work only writen the epsg number

"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "32720" } },

The problems come because the documentation of open layers is very minimal.
 Also the argument defaultDataProjection have different use on the 4.x version.

I read that the new GeoJson format will lack support for CRS,
 from my point of view is a great mistake
 so the new name of GeoJson must to be:

"onlyWGS84GeoJson"

and left the original GeoJson to the people that can deal 
 with projections.

Greetings